# How to append a Blob to FormData

Tags: javascript, blob, form-data

```
var myBlob = new Blob(["This is my blob content"], {type : "text/plain"});
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("clip",myBlob)
```

The `Blob` is working fine:

```
myBlob: Blob
size: 341746
type: "text/plain"
```

But it is not being appended to the `FormData`:

[image]

Why is the `Blob` not showing up in the `FormData` ?

Comment: `fd.append('clip', myBlob, 'blobby.txt');` By the way, localStorage properties cast to Strings when possible.

Comment: @StackSlave I just copied and pasted incorrectly from my code : that was actually there ..  Corrected the question to show it.   What is the importance of your `localStorage` / strings  comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, actually, according to [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) specs, there is no way to inspect form data elements within a simple `console.log()` or debugger.

So the only way to inspect the items within it is to iterate through its [entires](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjc_6n65vDqAhVlQt8KHWRLCcoQFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2Fentries&usg=AOvVaw2qgd3d2b4q3lNB9rowqJ68) like this:

```js
var myBlob = new Blob(["This is my blob content"], {type : "text/plain"});
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("clip",myBlob);

// Display the key/value pairs
for (var pair of fd.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
}
```